# Yellow leaves with Dried spots on chili leaves

Tags: diseases, chili, tropical

I have noticed this on my chili leaves (refer to photo). At first I thought it is happening on bottom leaves but I spotted some top leaves as well. I have noticed that the infection is spreading. The infected leaves seem to just fall off on touch.

[image]